# Getting error when running the program

Tags: java

I have below code:

**ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {
    static boolean isDone = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In class A.");
        if (!isDone) {
            new ClassB();
            isDone = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
public class ClassB {
    ClassB () {
        ClassA.main(null);
    }
}
```

When running the program, I'm getting following output:

```
In class A.
In class A.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
```

It is printing "In class A." as expected, but why I'm getting stack over flow error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the flag `isDone` after calling `ClassB()`. So there is an infinite recursive call happening, which leads to `StackOverFlowError` when memory is reached.

Set the flag (`isDone`), before calling `ClassB();`.

As shown below:

```
if (!isDone) {
    isDone = true;
    new ClassB();
}
```

Comment: Logical mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite method call chain in your code that is causing the StackOverflowError. This is because you are calling the main method of `ClassA` from the constructor of `ClassB`. The if block in your main method will never finishing. The logical error in your code is the setting of flag(`isDone`) after the creation of `ClassB` instance instead of doing it before that.

Try changing the `if` block from

```
 if (!isDone) {
         new ClassB();
         isDone = true;
  }
```

to

```
 if (!isDone) {
         isDone = true;
         new ClassB();
  }
```